# Контекстное меню в классе не являющийся активностью

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, java, классы

Привет
Разрабатываю приложение с композитными компонентами, по этому уроку 
[Habrahabr.ru](http://habrahabr.ru/post/124879/)
И столкнулся с такой проблемой. Как мне сделать контекстное меню для компонента...
Вернее где описать сам "onCreateContextMenu" и "registerForContextMenu" ведь класс в котором описано все это дело, не является активностью??? Я запутался)

СКРИН АКТИВИТИ >>

[image: Imgur]

КОД КЛАССА

```
private Record parentRecord;

private LinearLayout Record;
private ImageView Smile;
private TextView TV_Date, TV_Month, TV_Year, TV_Time, TV_Header_Record, 
         TV_Text_Record, TV_Category, TV_Place, TV_DayWeek, NumRecord;


final int MENU_EDIT = 1;
final int MENU_DELETE = 2;
final int MENU_SHARING = 3;


public RecordFrame(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initCompantent();

}


private void initCompantent() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.record, this);

    Record = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Record);
     Record.setOnClickListener(Clck);
    Smile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Smile);
    TV_Category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_Category);
    TV_Date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV_Date);
    TV_Header_Record = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_Header_Record);
    TV_Month = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_Month);
    TV_Place = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_Place);
    TV_Text_Record = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_Text_Record);
    TV_Time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_Time);
    TV_DayWeek = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_DayWeek);
    TV_Year = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_Year);
    NumRecord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NumRecord);

    ((Activity) getContext()).registerForContextMenu(Record); // ПЫТАЛСЯ СДЕЛАТЬ ТАК, НО НИЧЕГО....
}

private final OnClickListener Clck = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), View_Record.class);            
        getContext().startActivity(intent);

    }
};

    // КОНТЕКСТНОЕ МЕНЮ
protected void onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu menu, View v,
        android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Record:
        menu.add(0, MENU_EDIT, 0, "Изменить");
        menu.add(0, MENU_SHARING, 0, "Опубликовать");
        menu.add(0, MENU_DELETE, 0, "Удалить");
        break;
    }
};



public void setNumRecord(String numrec) {
    NumRecord.setText(numrec);
}

public void setTV_Category(String category) {
    TV_Category.setText(category);
}

public void setTV_Date(String date) {
    TV_Date.setText(date);
}

public void setTV_Header_Record(String headrec) {
    TV_Header_Record.setText(headrec);
}

public void setTV_Month(String month) {
    TV_Month.setText(month);
}

public void setTV_Place(String place) {
    TV_Place.setText(place);
}

public void setTV_Text_Record(String record) {
    TV_Text_Record.setText(record);
}

public void setTV_Time(String time) {
    TV_Time.setText(time);
}

public void setTV_DayWeek(String dayweek) {
    TV_DayWeek.setText(dayweek);
}

public void setTV_Year(String year) {
    TV_Year.setText(year);
}

public Record getParentRecord() {
    return parentRecord;
}

public void setParentRecord(Record parentRecord){
    this.parentRecord = parentRecord;
    updateFieldsByParent();
}


private void updateFieldsByParent() {
    setNumRecord(parentRecord.getNumRecord());
    setTV_Category(parentRecord.getCategory());
    setTV_Date(parentRecord.getDate());
    setTV_DayWeek(parentRecord.getDayWeek());
    setTV_Header_Record(parentRecord.getHeader());
    setTV_Month(parentRecord.getMonth());
    setTV_Place(parentRecord.getPlace());
    setTV_Text_Record(parentRecord.getText());
    setTV_Time(parentRecord.getTime());
    setTV_Year(parentRecord.getYear());
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Если вы решили пользоваться `LayoutInflater`, то надо быть логичным до конца и использовать [`MenuInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html) - тогда будете сами создавать свое меню.

P.S. Из вашего кода так и неясно ваш класс от кого наследуется?

Comment: Спасибо за отклик.
Мне нужно контекстное меню, через длинный тап которое, а насколько я знаю MenuInflater используется при создании обычного меню...
Класс наследуем от класса который использовали в верстке — LinearLayout.

Comment: Ну ловите длинный тап - через `onLongClickListener()` и садите туда `MenuInflater`, если не устраивает `MenuInflater` сажайте на него [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)